# Close votes remains after question reopens?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Yesterday this question [A shorter but meaningful validation message for "This email is already subscribed"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21492/) got closed by my vote and moderator JonW. OP edited the question in a good way and it got reopened. That’s great, and do not happen often here.

[image: My Close vote]

But what puzzles me is that my close vote still remains. Shouldn’t close votes be discarded when a closed question is reopened? If not, at least the one casting the close vote should be able to withdraw the close vote after an edit. The behaviour to change after an edit is implemented on Up | Down votes, but why not on close votes?

Answer (score 2):

Close votes don't do that. However, apparently someone *else* has voted to close. When you click the close button it will still say you've already voted to close it because you only get one close and one reopen vote per question, no matter how many times it's reopened.

Comment: But that's what I want to overcome. If it was edited I should vote reopen instead of undo my close vote after it got closed. But what if the edit happened before the question gets closed, can I undo my close vote then?

Comment: @BennySkogberg oh, no, "retracting" close votes has been declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes popular opinion seems to be in your favor but I don't think that feature has been reconsidered